# Python Errno13 Permission Denied

Tags: python, csv

I'm getting a permission denied error when trying to use glob to get a filename list and csv to open csv files for dictionary reading. Here is my code:

```
import csv
import glob

#Filepath variable for the CSV files
path = "C:\\Users\\josh\\Data"

for filename in glob.glob(path):
    with open(filename) as csv_file:
        for row in csv.DictReader(csv_file):
            print row
```

I've tried running some file opening tests with the following code and it works perfectly. So I know I can open, read, write to this folder:

```
open('C:\\Users\\josh\\Data\\testing.txt', 'w').write('this is a test')
open('C:\\Users\\josh\\Data\\03142016.csv')
```

Lastly, here is the full traceback if that helps:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-10-49215e5eb704>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('C:/Users/josh/.spyder2/csvparser2.0.py', wdir='C:/Users/josh/.spyder2')

  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\sitecustomize.py", line 580, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "C:/Users/josh/.spyder2/csvparser2.0.py", line 41, in <module>
    with open(filename) as csv_file:

IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\\Users\\josh\\Data'
```

Any ideas? Thank you for your help.

Comment: I think this is probably a spyder issue, since you seem to be executing your code through ipython and spyder, what do you think the `wdir='C:/Users/josh/.spyder2'` means?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Right now you're doing:

```
path = "C:\\Users\\josh\\Data"

for filename in glob.glob(path):
```

`glob.glob()` on *only* a pathname without any special globbing characters (`*`, `?`, etc) will just return that pathname. In this case the directory name, which you're not allowed to `open()` since that doesn't make a lot of sense.

You probably intended to write:

```
glob.glob(path + '\\*'):
```

or:

```
glob.glob(path + '\\*.csv'):
```

### Bonus tip

You already figured out that using `open('C:\\Users\\josh\\Data\\03142016.csv')` works fine, which is a good first step in solving the problem. You could have found out the error by using basic "printf-debugging":

```
path = "C:\\Users\\josh\\Data"

for filename in glob.glob(path):
    print(filename)
    with open(filename) as csv_file:
        [.. trim ..]
```

This would have printed out `C:\\Users\\josh\\Data`, and not `C:\\Users\\josh\\Data\\03142016.csv` :-)

Lesson: when in doubt, `print()` out as many values as you can, and check if they're what you expect ;-)

Comment: That is correct. Thank you! One of those small things that my brain just kept missing apparently.

Comment: This is not the issue, if python recognized it as a directory the OP would be getting a `[Errno 21] Is a directory`

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen I think this is a OS-dependent thing. In POSIX systems there's the `EISDIR` error, but Windows often has different error codes (usually less specific). I didn't test this on Windows though...

Comment: that makes a lot of sense, I was so confused for a moment there.

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen Different subtly different/incompatible operating systems tend to do that to people ;-)